# How to solve this operation research problem using dual simplex method?

Tags: duality-theorems, simplex, operations-research

Maximize $$ z = 2x_1 -x_2 +x_3$$

Subject to constraints $$2x_1 + 3x_2 -5x_3 \ge 4$$
                                         $$-x_1 +9x_2 -x_3 \ge 3$$
                                         $$4x_1 +6x_2 +3x_3 \le 8$$
And $x_1, x_2, x_3 \ge 0$

I managed to solve this through simplex method(by 2 stage method) but I was asked solve it using dual simplex method, I found out that this cannot be solved by dual simplex since it doesn't meet the maximization optimality condition here which is the reduced costs in the z-row(or the values in the z-row in the initial table) must be always lesser than $0$ which is not the case here as coefficient of $x_2$ is 2 in the z-row.

Still our teacher says it can be solved by introducing another constraint which is $x_1 + x_3 \le M$ (where M is sufficiently large), now I am at a loss how to proceed further ?

I know the answer will be quiet huge and time taking but any type of help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sometimes called "big M" method. Seriously!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Find the optimal solution by the dual simplex algorithm

1. Add the artificial constraint $x_1 + x_3 \le M$ to the problem.
2. Write the problem in canonical form.
3. Add a slack variable to each inequality.
4. Write a simplex tableau for the problem.
   \begin{equation*}
     \begin{array}{lrrrl}
              \max & z = 2 x_1 &   - x_2 &   + x_3 &         \\
       \text{s.t.} &   - 2 x_1 & - 3 x_2 & + 5 x_3 & \le - 4 \\
                   &       x_1 & - 9 x_2 &   + x_3 & \le - 3 \\
                   &     4 x_1 & + 6 x_2 & + 3 x_3 &   \le 8 \\
                   &       x_1 &         &   + x_3 &   \le M
     \end{array} \\
     x_1, x_2, x_3 \ge 0
   \end{equation*}
   \begin{equation*}
     \begin{array}{rrrrrrrr|l}
           & x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & x_4 & x_5 & x_6 & x_7 &    \\ \hline
       x_4 &  -2 &  -3 &  -5 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 & -4 \\
       x_5 &   1 &  -9 &   1 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 & -3 \\
       x_6 &   4 &   6 &   3 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &  8 \\
       x_7 &   1 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &  M \\ \hline
           &  -2 &   1 &  -1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &  0
     \end{array}
   \end{equation*}
   Perform a pivot operation using $y_{7?}$ as a pivot to make all entries in the last row positive.
   \begin{equation*}
     \begin{array}{rrrrrrrr|l}
                x_7 &     \color{red}{1} & 0 &     \color{red}{1} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & M \\ \hline
                    &    \color{red}{-2} & 1 &    \color{red}{-1} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
       \text{ratio} & \color{red}{2/1=2} &   & \color{red}{1/1=1} &   &   &   &   &
     \end{array}
   \end{equation*}
   Here, we should choose the maximum ratio.  Therefore, we choose $y_{71}$ as a pivot element in the initial tableau.
   \begin{equation*}
     \begin{array}{rrrrrrrr|l}
       x_7 & 1^* & 0 &  1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & M \\ \hline
           &  -2 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
     \end{array}
   \end{equation*}
   We apply the dual simplex algorithm to the following tableau.
   \begin{equation*}
     \begin{array}{rrrrrrrr|l}
                  & x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & x_4 & x_5 & x_6 &  x_7 &        \\ \hline
              x_4 &   0 &  -3 &   7 &   1 &   0 &   0 &    2 & 2M  -4 \\
              x_5 &   0 &  -9 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   -1 & -M  -3 \\
              x_6 &   0 &   6 &  -1 &   0 &   0 &   1 & -4^* & -4M +8 \\
              x_1 &   1 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &    1 &      M \\ \hline
                  &   0 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &    2 &     2M \\
     \text{ratio} &     &     &   1 &     &     &     &  1/2 &
     \end{array}
   \end{equation*}
   \begin{equation*}
     \begin{array}{rrrrrrrr|l}
                  & x_1 &   x_2   &  x_3 & x_4 & x_5 &  x_6 & x_7 &      \\ \hline
              x_4 &   0 &     0   & 13/2 &   1 &   0 &  1/2 &   0 &    0 \\
              x_5 &   0 & -21/2^* &  1/4 &   0 &   1 & -1/4 &   0 &   -5 \\
              x_7 &   0 &  -3/2   &  1/4 &   0 &   0 & -1/4 &   1 & M -2 \\
              x_1 &   1 &   3/2   &  3/4 &   0 &   0 &  1/4 &   0 &    2 \\ \hline
                  &   0 &     4   &  1/2 &   0 &   0 &  1/2 &   0 &    4 \\
     \text{ratio} &     &  8/21   &      &     &     &    2 &     &
     \end{array}
   \end{equation*}
   \begin{equation*}
     \begin{array}{rrrrrrrr|l}
           & x_1 & x_2 &   x_3 & x_4 &   x_5 &   x_6 & x_7 &       \\ \hline
       x_4 &   0 &   0 &  13/2 &   1 &     0 &   1/2 &   0 &     0 \\
       x_2 &   0 &   1 & -1/42 &   0 & -2/21 &  1/42 &   0 & 10/21 \\
       x_7 &   0 &   0 &  3/14 &   0 &  -1/7 & -3/14 &   1 & M-9/7 \\
       x_1 &   1 &   0 & 11/14 &   0 &   1/7 &  3/14 &   0 &   9/7 \\ \hline
           &   0 &   0 & 25/42 &   0 &  8/21 & 17/42 &   0 & 44/21
     \end{array}
   \end{equation*}
   Hence, the optimal solution of the primal problem is $(\dfrac97,\dfrac{10}{21},0)^T$, with an optimal value of $\dfrac{44}{21}$.

### Find the optimal solution by GNU Octave

I post the Octave code for you to verify the optimal solution shown above.

```
octave:1> c = [2 -1 3]';
octave:2> A = [2 3 -5; -1 9 -1; 4 6 3];
octave:3> b = [4 3 8]';
octave:4> [x_max,z_max] = glpk(c,A,b,[0,0,0]',[],"UUL","CCC")
x_max =

   1.28571
   0.47619
   0.00000

z_max =  2.0952
```

Comment: Well a big big thanks