# Find the optimal solution using dual simplex algorithm

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, simplex

Maximize $ z=-5x_1+10x_2+8x_3$
subject to constraints

$3x_1+5x_2+2x_3<=60$

$4x_1+4x_2+4x_3>=72$

$x_1<=0$

$x_1,x_2,x_3>=0$

Thanks for help :)

Comment: At which step did a problem occur? One important hint: For $=$  and $\geq$ constraints you need an artificial variable each.

Comment: In the initial table on row all values are not$ <=0$ but i do not know what to do next :(

Comment: It´s not clear for me what do you mean by your comment. Please rephrase it. Something what is obvious is that $x_1=0$ if you combine the constraints $x_1\leq 0$ and $x_1\geq 0$. Therefore you can drop the terms with $x_1$ at the objetive function and the constraints.

Comment: The best you can do is to show your initial table.

Comment: One second pls :)

Comment: Here is the $\LaTeX$-code for a table:   `$$\begin{matrix}
    1 & x & x^2 \\
    1 & y & y^2 \\
    1 & z & z^2 \\
    \end{matrix}$$`

gives

$$\begin{matrix}1 & x & x^2 \\
    1 & y & y^2 \\
    1 & z & z^2 \\
    \end{matrix}$$ You can copy the code and adjust it.

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/HYTIwMK.png

Comment: Shouldn't these 2 values be smaller or equal to 0 at the beginning ?

Comment: all online calculators say that there is no solution but my teacher insists this can be solved using this method

Comment: I´ve looked at your upload. You cannot just multiply the second constraint by (-1) to get an $\leq$-constraint. You have to introduce an **artificial variable** like  $4x_1+4x_2+4x_3-s_2+a_2=72$.

Comment: So now i have no idea what to do next. During lessons our teacher was just multiplying by -1

Comment: It seems that the dual simplex algorithm is not the equivalent to the 2-Phase Simlex algorithm. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1542880/how-to-solve-this-operation-research-problem-using-dual-simplex-method?rq=1) is an equivalent question with an answer.

Comment: Yes, i saw it but is it possible to solve this problem without using big M method?

Comment: @callculus I saw it but i don't know how to use big M method in my case